# Using LINQ with databases other than SQL Server Express 2005

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, postgresql

I'm just starting to look into using LINQ for my database (and XML, and data object!) needs, but need to decide on which database to go with.  I've been reading Pro LINQ, and it says that currently, LINQ in .NET 3.5 only supports SQL Server.  I have done some googling, and have found references to using LINQ with MySQL and PostgreSQL (my other two DB options), but they are refer to DLinq, which I understand to be the predecessor of LINQ to DB.

I've read interesting and informative comparisons of the three databases [here](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL) and [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/51-Cross-Compare-of-SQL-Server,-MySQL,-and-PostgreSQL.html), but am still torn.  I do not have any in-depth database experience, so it's important to be able to get the software installed and configured easily, or at least be easy to figure out how to compile a list of steps to configure it.  I definitely want to have transactional support as well.  But most importantly -- I want to use LINQ.

I'd like to hear what everyone here is using, whether it's SQL Server because LINQ supports it natively, or the other two with some additional component for LINQ support that I haven't yet found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [devart's dotConnect provider](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/) for Linq-to-Oracle and have been very pleased.  They try and make the functionality **match Linq-to-SQL as close as possible**, which seems to be what you're looking for.

They have providers for:

- Oracle
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- SQL Server

From a cost perspective, it's an excellent deal I'd say, just pay for developer seats, no server licensing.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, I'll look into it.  Hopefully they support something other than Oracle, which in my limited experience is a daunting installation, as I am not a DBA or anything close.  :)

Comment: well maybe I should have clicked the link before commenting.  I'll read up on it!

Comment: @Filip Ekberg - They have an Entity Framework provider I think...to be honest I don't know as of right now, they didn't when we started this project a few months ago.

Comment: it is very reasonably priced, so that's great.  I still have to decide whether or not SQL Server Express is "good enough".  I have much more research to do, but hopefully others will post about similar products like dotConnect!

Comment: Unfortunatly they don't support Access.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg - Well the question is tagged `database`, so I was excluding Access...

Comment: Access is as much of a database as MySQL is.

Comment: Not really, why wouldn't Access be a "database" ? You do know the definition of a Database / DBMS ? And what can you do in MySQL that you can't in Access?

Comment: @Filip Ekberg - Large number of concurrent connections (Jet limitation), Over 255 concurrent users, Database over 2GB, Transactions, Triggers, Stored procedures (stored queries don't compare)...I could go on, basically lack of management tools and **any** level of scalability is what it lacks.  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2....(even SQL Server Express and Oracle XE are free) do a great deal more than access.  Yes, it's by definition a database, but putting it on the same level as MySQL or any other major RDBMS is a bit absurd.